# How to run a class as a jar file trough maven with antrun plugin

Tags: java, class, maven, ant, classpath

I have the following plugin configuration in my maven pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>prepare-database</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <configuration>
            <target name="run">
                <java fork="false"  failonerror="yes" classname="Test">
                    <arg line="arg1 arg2"/>
                </java>
            </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The class is located in a package under src/main/java the package is called com.a.b and the class file is called Test.java

```
package com.a.b;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        String arg1 = args[0];
        String arg2 = args[1];
        doStuff(arg1, arg2);
      }

    public static void doStuff(String arg1, String arg2)
      {
          System.out.println(arg1);
      }
}
```

When trying to execute the maven build that runs the ant task I get the following error:

> An Ant BuildException has occured: Could not find Test. Make sure you
>   have it in your classpath

I understand that the file can not be found but I have no clue what to do about it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just wondering if the name `Test` is causing the class to be excluded... perhaps try `class Foo` instead?

Comment: Test seems to be a valid java classname. That's probably not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [standard-directory-layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) article on the Maven site.

Source folder should be src/main/java (and not src/java/main)

Also, what exactly do you want to do with this ant target ? Do you simply need the fork ? Why can't you run it as a pure unit test, or a maven integration test and forget about the ANT target ?

H2 is well-suited for running in-memory. It only takes a couple of lines to connect to the DB and start testing, all inside the JVM, all using standard jUnit code.

```
 Class.forName("org.h2.Driver"); 
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:mytest", "sa", ""); 
 Statement sst = con.createStatement(); 
 sst.executeUpdate(SQL);
```

Comment: Ooops! Wrong path in the question. how ever the one in my project is correct like you stated src/main/java. I still see the error though.

Comment: If you do a mvn clean install, do you see the Test.class in \target\classes\com\a\b ?

Comment: No I don't All my other classes are in the places they should.

Comment: Can you add your entire directory layout to the question ?